# How to Add to Activity under OnClick?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm building an app which has three buttons to open each activity from the `Main Activity`.

The first activity (Inbox Activity) opens up fine, but every time I press the MMS button to open MMS Activity, the app crashes then opens up the MMS Activity. the same thing happens when i press the third button to open activity but even after pressing the third activity it opens the MMS activity not the third activity (SMS Activity). Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    Intent in = new Intent(this, MMSActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specifics but all I can say is the code is incorrect. I am assuming you are using xml to assign the buttons onClick (`android.onClick = "<function name>"`) to the onClick function. If so the code for onClick should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case(R.id.<inbox button id>:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case(R.id.<MMS button name>:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MMSActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case(R.id.<SMS button name>:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SMSActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
}
```

note <> represents the name you assign to the object in question.
I hope this helps you. If I got something wrong in my answer or understanding of the question, please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing this wrong.

First get your Button

```
Button inboxButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInbox);

// Then do setTag on the button, which uniquely allows button to be
// recognized in shared onClick Listener

inboxButton.setTag("InboxActivity");
inboxButton.setOnClickListener(this);

// get the mms button
Button mmsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mmsButton);
mmsButton.setTag("MMSActivity");
mmsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

// Finally get the tag for your view:


 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

  String tag = v.getTag() != null ? v.getTag().toString() : "";

  // If you set a tag
  if(!tag.trim().equals(""){
       // Check if it equals "InboxActivity"
        if(tag.equals("InboxActivity"){

            // Launch the intent
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);

          // Same for "MMSActivity"
         }else if(tag.equals("MMSActivity")){

         Intent in = new Intent(this, MMSActivity.class);
         startActivity(in);
       }else{
          // for debugging
           Toast.makeText(this, "Unrecognized tag...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } // end inside if, else if else

    } // end outer if

 } // end onClick
```